# Silverlight vs Adobe Air

Tags: silverlight, air

Now with Silverlight 3 (offline, out of browser stuff), what are the main differences between the two technologies?

Comment: At the time of asking, the main difference is that Adobe Air is not just a beta.

Answer (score 8):

There are some significant differences right now in the Beta, no idea if these will still be differences in the release version.

1. There is no way to hide the window chrome in Silverlight OOB.
2. No ability to create a notification tray icon.
3. Air apps can be multi-window, Silverlight OOB cannot.
4. Air apps have more access to the system, Silverlight apps are sandboxed.
5. There are differences in the install and update procedures, not sure of al of the details.

Answer (score 3):

AIR gives you access to the file system and a SQLite db. SL3 only lets you write to the file system with user interaction (a Save As dialog) and doesn't have any support for a DB in Isolated storage or on disk.

SLOOB runs in a sandbox still, so you're limited to the same cross-domain issues as a Silverlight app running in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

It's a three way war: Adobe AIR, MS Silverlight and Mozilla Prism.

Read [this](http://www.steveciske.com/post/Using-Silverlight-vs-Flash.aspx) blog-post and this [article](http://www.webdirections.org/the-state-of-the-web-2008/flash-silverlight-and-other-embedded-content/). A quote from the second article:

> Silverlight is the clear winner in terms of power, but as one of my colleagues pointed out the other day does it matter?  His point was that Flash has an incredible penetration rate.  According to Adobe it’s in the 99% range.  When considering rolling out a new product that requires a plug-in why introduce another barrier to adoption?

and another one from the second:

> We then asked of those who answered yes which formats they use. Unsurprisingly, given how long it has been available, Flash leads with 61% of respondents. More surprising was Silverlight’s very small market share of a little over 2%, essentially the same as that of the Real format. Quicktime did surprisingly well, at just under 20%.

As for VOIP support in SL read [this](http://www.techcrunchit.com/2009/02/03/tringme-finds-a-way-to-make-voip-calls-from-microsoft-silverlight/).

Read up on Prism [here](http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/prism/).

Comment: I wish PRISM had a chance.. it's not pushed hard enough by Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Dave said, Silverlight seems to be missing device support (microphone and web cam).

Comment: This is planned for the first release post 3 (at MIX, it sounded like there would be a 3.1 release and this was in it)

Comment: Is there any news of what will come in a post 3 release? And when it will come out?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'd like to point out, that nobody else has mentioned is (and I'm not picking favorites when I say this, as we use Air/Flex for a project at my job):

Adobe doesn't have the talent needed to create quality run times and IDEs for developers.  Their ideas are fine, it's the execution of those ideas that I doubt.  I think we can all agree that Visual Studio is light years ahead of any IDE out there.  Quality wise I'd even go as far as to say that VS2005 is better made than anything on the market (it's now 2011) 6yrs later.

If you feel Flex/Air meets your needs better, my all means, go with it.  But if feel either platform will give you what you want, I'd say Silverlight wins every time.  It's more mature, it's substantially more stable.

Our biggest headache for our commercial app is that Air does not managed garbage collection well, for the past year and a half, our app has suffered from slowdown, the only resolution is to do a nightly reboot on a kiosk because we nest objects inside objects, once you hit the 3rd nesting, it seems Air cannot flush those objects correctly, Adobe is will aware of it, and considering how much time has passed and all the newer versions, Adobe has no resolution.  That is the sign of poor run times and Adobe developers who just aren't very good.  Despite the fact people love to bash MS, these days their platforms are pretty reliable is reliable overall, especially their .NET runtimes.  Adobe feels like Microsoft circa 1997, they're years away from offering reliable solutions.

PS: I'm sure a couple koolaid drinking Adobe devs will be down voting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only minor changes are necessary to run a Silverlight app on the desktop, the differences are in implementation details.  Silverlight is a .NET-space framework based on WPF.  Flash/Flex/AIR are proprietary Adobe products based on ActionScript.

In terms of capability, they seem to be roughly equal with complementary strenghts and weaknesses.  Example:  SL3 will have GPU and pixel shader support.  The latest Flash as Inverse Kinematics.  Different strokes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the users standpoint I like the Silverlight installation process a lot more... Specially on the Mac - Air app installation is unnatural (to many clicks and processbars) but oneclick Silverlight install is nice :)